# Can a P-value be calculated with these 4 statistics?

Tags: mean, p-value, standard-deviation

This is all you know.

There are two farming plots, they are adjacent to each other, with the same soil type and irrigation methods. Yields for the two plots are available for 15 years.

Plot 1 has an average yield of 158.6. (crop/acre)
Plot 2 has an average yield of 159.2.

The maximum difference between a Plot 1 reading and a Plot 2 reading was 4.8%.

A new fertilizer was used for Plot 2 this year.

The 16th pair of readings is plot 1 = 158.1 ; plot 2 = 178.4

The null hypothesis is that the means are equal. The alternate hypothesis is that they are not equal.  (The significant level used would be the standard 0.05.)

Is there enough information here to reject the null hypothesis?

I am assuming the plant sizes on a given farming plot will be normally distributed, as there are consistent plot characteristics, and consistent irrigation and sunlight.

Comment: The p-value is not the probability that "*the change is plot 2 did not occur by chance*" so it it not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What is a "Set 1 reading" and how is it related to the two plots?

Comment: @RobertLong  I don't agree, however I reworded the question to "What is the probability that most recent plot 2 result did not occur by chance?"

Comment: @whuber.  Sorry, "Set 1" is supposed to be "Plot 1."  All the "Sets" are supposed to be "Plots."  That should make it clear, so please un-close this.

Comment: You don't agree with what ? The title literally asks for a p value : "*Can a P-value be calculated with these 4 statistics ?*" yet the probability you are asking for is not a p value.

Comment: I already did, but it's worth remarking there's still insufficient information to answer your explicit question ("what is the probability..."), even when it's understood you are looking for some kind of p-value.  There may be enough information to *guess* all the assumptions required to obtain an answer of 0.999999999.  The answer 15/16 can be supported using fewer assumptions (and an answer of 0 is plausible, too).  This range indicates just how much the answer depends on the assumptions you make.

Comment: I notice that all four of us who have interacted here potentially have four different interpretations of this question.  I am reluctantly reclosing the question until it can be stated more clearly.  (Unless your question truly is the one in the title, in which case the alternative interpretations already answer it in the negative!)

Comment: @whuber  I am interested in the question in the title (p-value).  I updated the post again, changing the p-value question to something that should end whatever is being nick-picked about. Please un-close the question. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertLong  I updated the part about the p-value test, to just state a standard hypothesis test.  I don't know what you were complaining about, but that is completely gone now.

Comment: I'm not complaining - that's a strange term to use. The title of the post is "*Can a P-value be calculated with these 4 statistics?*". So do you mean the probability of these data IF the null hypothesis is true ? If so, then the answer to your question is: No.

Comment: @whuber I've posted a new, related but different (and better) question on this, which should clarify (for me) how I should be looking at a related problem design: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511654/how-do-i-test-significance-for-this-quasi-experimental-test-data

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are asking whether there is a significant difference between plot 1 and plot 2 (with and without fertilizer). In order to solve that you need at least the variances of your yields of both plots.

However: Which test to apply depends on several assumptions. So in general (if you have the raw data) you should proceed as follows:

1. Test whether the data of the two plots are normally distributed
2. If there is no normal distribution, use the Mann-Whitney-U-Test, else go to step 3)
3. Test whether the variances of the two plots differ significantly by applying an F test. If there is no significant difference of the variances perform a 2-sample t test, else apply the Welch test.

All those tests will finally deliver the probability that the detected difference has occurred by chance.

Comment: The point is that I don't have the raw data, so I don't have the variance. The variance information is limited to the max difference of 4.8%, and the averages of 158.6 and 159.2 over 15 points, when the expected averages of both plots is that they would be identical (less normal variance).

Comment: I cannot find anything in your question, Kyle, that implies the plots should be expected to have the same means, but the averages you do give (158.6 and 159.2) differ and this suggests the plots should *not* be expected to have the same means. This vagueness in how the question might be interpreted is a problem for us.  Could you edit your post to clarify the question?

Comment: @whuber  If I randomly generate two sets of 15 numbers, with a mean of 159 and a standard deviation of 7 (for example), the resulting averages of the two sets will not be identical.  Why do averages of 158.6 and 159.2, with 15 sets of points, seem odd to you?  Two adjacent farming plots with the same seed, fertilizer, and irrigation would be expected to have very similar yields.

Comment: They don't seem "odd" at all.  However, they don't tell us what your null hypothesis ought to be, either, nor do they reveal much about the *distributions* of those pairs of 15 numbers.  You have now articulated a null hypothesis, but the answer to "is there enough information to reject it" is (for any significance threshold lower than 1/16) an unequivocal no, for the reasons given in my second comment to your question.

Comment: @whuber  Are you considering that these plots each contain many instances (plot rows, etc.) ?  Consider you divide the plots into rows, and you get 20 rows, with a mean and SD. (Or consider each plant.) The mean equals the given plot mean.  Now you have two samples, normally distributed, and can run a t-test.  After all, each individual plant was given the new fertilizer.

Comment: I think the rank sum test ignores the pairing in observations of the two plots during the same year. If the soil type and irrigation methods are identical, and the plots are adjacent, then each year of observation shares major sources of variation (soil, irrigation, and weather conditions), whereas measure between years would vary in weather, so this really seems more appropriate for a signed rank test in your second point. Also: in your point 3: the Welch test is identical to the unpaired t test when variances are equal, so just always perform Welch's t test?

Comment: I am considering all the information you have supplied, Kyle, without making additiional assumptions.  One such additional assumption would be the "normally distributed" statement made in your latest comment: that is nowhere to be found in the question.

Comment: @whuber - The plant sizes of the same plants on the same plot will be normally distributed - assuming the plot is consistent.  Also, this is a farming plot, not some back yard plot. I added the assumption to the description.

Comment: You are reaching the point where you are asking for an agronomist's opinion, not a statistician's!  From our perspective, once you adopt the assumptions of normality and temporal independence, you're done, because it's obvious this new yield difference is inconsistent with the summary of the first 15 years; but without those assumptions, you cannot conclude much.  That alone may be useful information, because it shows that if you choose to proceed as if the fertilizer made a difference, you will be relying on these specific assumptions (which can be examined and monitored).